# range of numbers in match statement php

Tags: php

How can I get a result from a range of number is a match-statement ?
I know the code is not correct, but I cant figure it out.

```
<?php

    $amount = 5001;
    $result = match(true){
        $amount >= 2000 => '1,5%',
        $amount >= 5000 => '5%',
        $amount >= 10000 => '10%',
        default => '0%',
    };
    echo "The discount is: $result"
?>`your text`
```

I want to get for instance 5% discount when the $amount is 5001. And match($amount) .... also doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing a `>=` (greater than or equal to) comparison you'll need to put the values you're comparing to in descending order (similar to example #4 in the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.match.php)).

This is because it will evaluate the conditions in the order it finds them. If one matches, it will use it, and stop. 5001 is greater than 2000, so that satisfies your first condition, and that's the end of the matching.

This:

```
$amount = 5001;
$result = match (true) {
    $amount >= 10000 => '10%',
    $amount >= 5000 => '5%',
    $amount >= 2000 => '1,5%',
    default => '0%',
};
echo "The discount is: $result";
```

...does what you're expecting. Working demo: https://3v4l.org/aWXgoi